# C# ListViewItemCollection in Settings

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem, setting

Is there a way to add a setting in a C# application with the type `ListViewItemCollection` or should i use something different, like an `Object[]` maybe?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, or easy, if it is possible. Personally, I used a csv file that I read to make a list of parameters.

Comment: @Zaphod Thanks, I ended up doing that, Didn't find any easy way to use a Collection anyways